# Multiple sliders on one page using Ayaslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, jquery-plugins

I can't seem to get multiple sliders on one page using the [Ayaslider jquery plugin](https://github.com/mamod/ayaSlider). The latest github version says he fixed that, but when I update my source code in ayaSlider.js it completely breaks [my current slider](http://www.t2research.com/). It looks like I am upgrading from the [second commit version](https://github.com/mamod/ayaSlider/commit/4156ef0f615102451bb49de5a083da4f3254bf63), which looks like it was in js but is now switching to jquery.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

I am currently enqueuing the google hosted jquery library 1.8.1.

Also, in case it helps, my custom.js code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#slider').ayaSlider({
       easeIn : 'easeOutBack',
       easeOut : 'linear',
       delay : 4000,
/*     timer : jQuery('#header'), */
       previous : jQuery('.prev'),
       next : jQuery('.next')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this, the solution is simple. Copy the code in the custom.js doc and give the first line a new id to reference:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#slider').ayaSlider({
       easeIn : 'easeOutBack',
       easeOut : 'linear',
       delay : 4000,
/*     timer : jQuery('#header'), */
       previous : jQuery('.prev'),
       next : jQuery('.next')
    });

jQuery('#slider2').ayaSlider({
       easeIn : 'easeOutBack',
       easeOut : 'linear',
       delay : 4000,
/*     timer : jQuery('#header'), */
       previous : jQuery('.prev'),
       next : jQuery('.next')
    });
});
```